# How to filter Accounts.createUser options data?

Tags: javascript, meteor, passwords

Making a registration part on my meteor project.
I'm using an "**accounts-password**" module and I want to know, how can I filter or modify data in "options" parameter?

[Accounts.createUser(options, [callback])](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-createUser) - it stores username, email, password.

For example, I want to prevent users create usernames with special symbols (!#@$), like : `username.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/ig, "")`
How I can configure that?

I was trying "Accounts.onCreateUser" function, but it's only helps with "profile"(additional) info.

Comment: Try to filter client side - is not effective, because somebody can use developer console to register

Answer (score 0):

`Accounts.onCreateUser()` allows you to modify the entire user document. You can examine the `username` field and replace characters there as much as you'd like.

Example:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser((options, user) => {
  user.username = user.username.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/ig, "")
  return user;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at [`Accounts.onCreateUser()`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsServer-onCreateUser):

> ARGUMENTS
>
> **func** *Function*
>
> Called whenever a new user is created. Return the new user object, or throw an `Error` to abort the creation.

So, in order to *prevent* users from using any special characters in username you should do something like this:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser((options, user) => {
  const re = new RegExp('^[a-z0-9]+$', 'i');
  if (!re.test(user.username)) {
    throw new Error('invalid-username', 'Entered username is invalid');
  }
  ...
});
```